ElasticSearch - Field Types
Currently using elastic search Serverless, I have a field called street number , currently it's stored as a text. It contains values which are both string and text:
[100, 101A, 102A, 103, 105-B, 150,]
My use case is I want to use a range query to get all street numbers between 100 & 110. It should output all values including the string values.
My questions is
What's the best way to store this data and retrieve it?

I would probably separate the number and the letter particle. Here are some ideas
